# Is there any way of using Cordova Plugins in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, cordova, google-cloud-functions, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to create firebase dynamic-link when a document gets created in my database and update the same document with field shareable_link : created_dynamic_link.

How can I use Cordova Plugin **Cordova plugin for Firebase Dynamic Links**  inside Firebase Function **onCreate()** event which gets triggered whenever new document is created in my database and I update the document available in snapshot of **onCreate()** event with dynamic-link created by mentioned Cordova plugin?

I don't know if I can include Cordova plugins right away in Firebase functions.

Also, are there any other alternatives?

**PS** : I thought to including cordova plugins since I am building an android app using Ionic-framework with cordova plugins.

**EDIT** : onCreate() is a Firebase Cloud Function event https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use Cordova with Firebase. Regarding the Cordova plugin for Firebase Dynamic Links, I believe you are mentioning the plugin on Github [here](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks). This plugin seems to be developed only for iOS and Android, so, in case you are developing for these environments, you should be good to go, using the variables on your `onCreate()` method. In case you are not, I believe you will need to adapt the code to your needs.

**However, it's not possible to to integrate Cordova plugin to Cloud Functions.**

Besides that, I found these two below articles with tutorials and information on using Firebase with Cordova - they are messaging apps, but I believe you should be able to get further information on the way you can integrate and use both together.

- [Cordova Firebase Plugin](https://docs.monaca.io/en/tutorials/firebase/)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging Integration for Cordova Hybrid Apps](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/mobile-app-development/firebase-cloud-messaging-integration-for-cordova-hybrid-apps/)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, this is not what I am looking for. I know the usage of **Cordova Firebase Plugin**. I need to use the cordova plugin in Firebase Cloud Function : firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Comment: Hi @sachinrathod as far as I know and could check, this is not possible. You won't be able to integrate Cordova plugin to Cloud Functions. I would recommend you to raise a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) for this to be check by Google in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for while. And yes I will raise a Feature Request.

Comment: Hi @sachinrathod thanks for letting me know! If you think the information I provided helped you, please, consider upvoting or accepting my answer - I have updated it with my last comment.

Comment: Can you please write the sentence "However, it's not possible to to integrate Cordova plugin to Cloud Functions." in bold so that people looking answer for similar question gets to know that as of now Cordova cannot be integrated with cloud functions.

Comment: Hi @sachinrathod thanks for pointing out that change! It's indeed better to look. I have just updated the answer as you mentioned.